# JPA's FetchType.LAZY doesn't work?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

My provider is:
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

My Entity code is:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( { @NamedQuery(name = "Bank.findAll", query = "select o from Bank o") })
@Table(name = "B_BANK")
public class Bank implements Serializable {

private final static String ID_GENERATOR = "Bank";

private Long id;
private User modifier;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = ID_GENERATOR)
@SequenceGenerator(name = ID_GENERATOR, allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "sq_B_BANK")
@Column(name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "modifier")
public User getModifier() {
    return modifier;
}

public void setModifier(User modifier) {
    this.modifier = modifier;
}
```

}

And my test code is just:

```
    entityManagerHelper = new EntityManagerHelper("Model", isAutoCommit);

   List l = entityManagerHelper.getEntityManager().createQuery("select b from Bank b").getResultList();
```

However in my console I had this:

SELECT id, modifier FROM B_BANK
SELECT id, CREATION_DATE, MODIFICATION_DATE, modifier, creator FROM B_USER WHERE (id = ?)
    bind => [2]

Therefore it seems that JPA queried for the User that I put fetch = FetchType.LAZY over it!
I am wondering why JPA queried for the User too.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer is true, EclipseLink uses weaving to implement lazy fetching for OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships.  If you are not run in a container environment, then you would have to add in an agent or setup your entities to be statically woven to use lazy on 1:1s as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Dynamic_Weaving  and here http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/app_dev007.htm